# Argument missing exception - While converting Array to MemoryStream

Tags: c#

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileData.FileData1.ToArray());
Image showImage = null;

using (System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))
{
    returnImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    MemoryStream msSave = new MemoryStream();
    showImage = FixedSize(returnImage, returnImage.Width, returnImage.Height);
    int hei = showImage.Height;
    int wid = showImage.Width;
    showImage.Save(msSave, imageFormat);
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(msSave.ToArray());
}
```

It was all working fine till sometime ago :/

[image]

Comment: What changed at the time that it stopped working?

Comment: This has nothing to do with converting a byte array to a memory stream, it has everything to do with the fact that the image cannot be read from the memory stream. Most likely the byte array does not contain the bytes that make up a valid image. You should look at the code that provides that array, and not the code in the question.

Comment: Don't screen shot the Exception popup. Use Copy exception detail to the clipboard and paste that. The details will be better.